# Adobe Air webview behaves differently from Native-driven Webview

Tags: android, webview, air

We're seeing some weird issues with Webviews from our SDK when they're being driven through Adobe Air. When debugging this, I inspected the `window.screen` and `window.devicePixelRatio` variables, and found a rather odd thing on high-resolution phones:

Native (Correct):

```
availWidth: 640
availHeight: 360
devicePixelRatio: 3
```

Air Plugin (Incorrect):

```
availWidth: 1920
availHeight: 1080
devicePixelRatio: 3
```

Now our SDK devs are asking me to fix the layout issues this is causing, but this is leading to a game of whack-a-mole because this causes regressions on the "native" webview. What I found in research is that phonegap experiences the same issues. Now, my question is this:

**What is actually causing this behavior in Adobe Air? Is a default being overridden by it? Is it setting some property on the WebView class which is then applied to all webviews?**